# Netty Frame Decoding based on Header

Tags: java, netty, hornetq

i am using netty 3.4.5 version. As i receive packets from network, the length of the frame is based on header. i.e

header1-->data with length 70 bytes.

header2-->data with length 140 bytes.

header3-->data with length 28 bytes.

i want to use **lengthbasedframedecoder** in netty. please suggest me how to do this. 
Also suggest me if there is any other way to do it.

thank you

Comment: Actually this is not a length field based frame if the `headerX` not indicates the length of the remain bytes .

Comment: @jilen please give an idea to achieve above scenario...

Comment: After reading netty source code, I find the easiest way is to override `getUnadjustedFrameLength` method in `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`(that requires length of `header1,header2,header3` are same  )

Comment: for example, if your header is a 4 bytes int, you may override that method as ```switch(buf.getUnsignedInt) {case header1 : return 70; case header2: return 140;}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `header1`, `header2`,`header3` are with same length, you could do this by override the `getUnadjustedFrameLength` in `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` like this.

```
switch(buf.getUnsignedInt) { //get header here
  case header1 : return 70; 
  case header2: return 140;
  case header3: return 28;
}
```

Comment: i Didn't check with this code. Have u checked it.??